# Excel categories from text with brackets to preset labels

Tags: excel, formula

Hope you are well.

One of my colleagues has to do a report that has 1000's of line and has to put every line into a type of report so we can work with that data for further reporting. The problem is she is doing it manually and I wanted to help her with a solution but I couldn't find one so far so please help me.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPWbt.png

Another sample here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/78eku.png

As you can see in the picture, trying to put in column R, the type of the report performed using some kind of formula to make it faster and easier, instead of going manually over all of them, using column B - Title. The problem is they use this convention for titles that use square brackets and give me errors all the time and they don't even keep that convention for all of them. Cells have different formats, content and length.
Has anyone worked with something like this before?
Do you have any solution I could give a try?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

See if you can figure this one out.
[image]

Basicaly you find brackets you need and then extract text between those brackets.

Comment: As I said in the post, I am trying to put them in one column R, based on the task type, not to split and extract the text. As you can see, titles are different length and different format, not all off them have the same information in the exact same bracket number. And when cell doesn't have brackets, I will probably get an error. What I need is more complicated than what you posted. Thanks.!

Comment: Ah my bad, I didn't examine your sheets well enough. I am out of ideas now. Appologies.